# grails 2.4.2 production deployment on Tomcat 7 triggers fatal error

Tags: tomcat, grails, grails-orm, scaffolding

On deploying a Grails 2.4.2 webapp to a Tomcat 7 server with security enabled, I get the following in a stacktrace and the app will not start. I have run `grails clean` before `grails war` and searched everywhere for a hint on this, with no luck.

It seems obvious to me that this is a permissions error when Grails/Groovy attempts to generate some dynamic scaffolding code, however I can't find a way to specify that these files need to be written somewhere else.

```
script14079441961801874947311.groovy: 8: Fatal error occurred applying query transformations [ access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/usr/local/tomcat/TomcatSandbox/Box/script14079441961801874947311.groovy" "read")] to source [script14079441961801874947311.groovy]. Please report an issue.
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/usr/local/tomcat/TomcatSandbox/Box/script14079441961801874947311.groovy" "read")
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:372)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:559)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:888)
    at java.io.File.isDirectory(File.java:838)
    at java.io.File.toURI(File.java:732)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.query.transform.DetachedCriteriaTransformer.isDomainClass(DetachedCriteriaTransformer.java:1316)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.query.transform.DetachedCriteriaTransformer.visitField(DetachedCriteriaTransformer.java:196)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1055)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:50)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.query.transform.DetachedCriteriaTransformer.visitClass(DetachedCriteriaTransformer.java:174)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.query.transform.GlobalDetachedCriteriaASTTransformation.visit(GlobalDetachedCriteriaASTTransformation.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformationVisitor$3.call(ASTTransformationVisitor.java:319)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:923)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:585)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:561)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:538)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:286)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:259)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:245)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:203)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:213)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader$parseClass$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin.createScaffoldedInstance(ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin.groovy:184)
    at ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin.this$2$createScaffoldedInstance(ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin.groovy)
    at ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin$this$2$createScaffoldedInstance$2.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
    at ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin.configureScaffoldingController(ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin.groovy:139)
    at ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin.this$2$configureScaffoldingController(ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin.groovy)
    at ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin$this$2$configureScaffoldingController.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin.configureScaffolding(ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin.groovy:114)
    at ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin.this$2$configureScaffolding(ScaffoldingGrailsPlugin.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: which user and permissions for that user to launch the app

Comment: I have a user on someone else's server, and very few permissions, one of the missing ones is my ability to see what permissions I have been assigned :)

Comment: perhaps get a system admin for the server to check your permissions (and assign more rights to you to at least run the app)

Comment: Yep, following that thread with the company at the same time as hunting down other fixes.